# low Map with faster rcnn model

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

I want to build Faster-RCNN model to detect human i followed this article https://towardsdatascience.com/faster-r-cnn-object-detection-implemented-by-keras-for-custom-data-from-googles-open-images-125f62b9141a
The problem that the mAP (mean average precision) doesn’t increase as the loss decreases. The max mAP i get is 0.355.
Please i need your help to find a solution for this issue as soon as possible!
or Can somebody please refer me good sources to build a strong model with faster rcnn to detect human using pascal voc dataset.

Comment: First, there are numerous problems with your post: 1) https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question 2) https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 3) https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic (specifically point 4). Now that's out of the way, depending on the data, number of epochs and other factors, 0.35 sounds like a decent result. It's usually not super intuitive to interpret though, so I'd suggest you additionally use IOU during training/debug to get a feeling of how things are progressing. Again, impossible to help you without more info.

Comment: Thank you so much for your respond, I use pascal voc as dataset, I extracted only  the person class (2000 images). After training 751k batches, i got a map with 0.355 and this value doesn't change ( i got also the same value after  training 1359k batches) I changed the parameters (learning rate, optimizers ..) several times also i used IOU during training but in vain! I followed this github code: https://github.com/RockyXu66/Faster_RCNN_for_Open_Images_Dataset_Keras/blob/master/frcnn_train_vgg.ipynb.